# js: array.reduce does not accumulate underlying values correctly

Tags: javascript

```
arr = [ 

    {
       day: "monday",
       ages: [1,5,2]
    },

    {
       day: "tuesday",
       ages: [9]
    },

    {
       day: "monday",
       ages: [22,24,28]
    },

    {
       day: "tuesday",
       ages: [19]
    },

]
```

I want the result to be an object that has each day as a key and the values as arrays:

expected:

```
{
    monday: [1,5,2,22,24,28],
    tuesday: [9,19]
}
```

I tried using reduce as follows:

```
x = arr.reduce((acc,curr) => {
    acc[curr.day] = []
    acc[curr.day].push(curr.ages)
    return acc
})
```

but it gives me:

```
{
    ages: [1,5,2],
    day: "tuesday", 
    monday: [22,24,28],
    tuesday: [19]
}
```

why would it add `ages` and `day` as keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps when you specify the initial value for the reducer (ie: `{}`) so you can simply check to see if the property is there and if so, add to it, and if not, set it.

```js
const arr = [ 
    {
       day: "monday",
       ages: [1,5,2]
    },

    {
       day: "tuesday",
       ages: [9]
    },

    {
       day: "monday",
       ages: [22,24,28]
    },

    {
       day: "tuesday",
       ages: [19]
    },
];

const result = arr.reduce((acc,curr) => {
    acc[curr.day] = acc[curr.day] ? [...acc[curr.day], ...curr.ages] : curr.ages; 
    return acc;
}, {});
console.log(result);
```

For the second argument to `Array.reduce(Func, InitialValue)` the general rule is that it is needed when you need to do something more complex with the accumulator before modifying it. In the below example, you can see that a simple `reduce` function add ints doesn't require an initial value. But the second example where we need to check to see if the `acc` contains the `curr` before adding it to the `acc`, you'll want to initialize `acc` is an empty array. otherwise, `acc` is undefined in the first run, and therefore `acc.find` will throw a null exception.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

// Simple summing of ints
console.log(arr.reduce( (acc, curr) => acc += curr) );

// Needing to do something with the accumulator before modiyfing it
const result = arr.reduce( (acc, curr) => {
  const found = acc.find(a => a === curr);
  if (found) {
    // do something
  }
  return acc;
});
```

From the docs:

InitialValue

> A value to use as the first argument to the first call of the
> callback. If no initialValue is supplied, the first element in the
> array will be used as the initial accumulator value and skipped as
> currentValue. Calling reduce() on an empty array without an
> initialValue will throw a TypeError.

Answer (score 2):

Missing initial value in reduce `{}`, then array is not reused in each iteration , and finally arrays are not concatenated.

```js
arr = [ 

    {
       day: "monday",
       ages: [1,5,2]
    },

    {
       day: "tuesday",
       ages: [9]
    },

    {
       day: "monday",
       ages: [22,24,28]
    },

    {
       day: "tuesday",
       ages: [19]
    },

]

console.log(arr.reduce((acc,curr) => {
    acc[curr.day] = acc[curr.day] || []
    acc[curr.day] = acc[curr.day].concat(curr.ages)
    return acc
}, {}));
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take a [logical nullish assignment `??=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment) for assigning empty array and push spreaded array and take an empty object as start value for the accumulator.

```
x = arr.reduce((acc,curr) => {
    acc[curr.day] ??= [];
    acc[curr.day].push(...curr.ages);
    return acc;
}, {});
```

Comment: This code would also work with the good old `||` operator that has greater support (arrays can't be falsy).

Comment: @FZs, `??=` prevents superfluous assignment, like the new `||=`.

Comment: That's right, I've just mentioned it as `??=` is a *very new* feature, and not everyone transpile their projects. Btw, I'd use `(acc[curr.day] || (acc[curr.day] = [])).push(...curr.ages);` that short-circuits as well.